# How to close a VB window from another VB window

Tags: vb6

I need to close a VB6 form from another VB6 form. I tried the following in form_unload but dint work:

```
End
unload(form_name)
me.close  
set obj_formname = nothing  
unload(me)
```

**Note: I just need the specific window to get closed but application should not get closed**

Please help me if i miss something

Comment: could you post some more code? how you are creating and displaying the window.

Comment: "me" is the current form, so that is definetly wrong as you want to close the other form ... i guess the problem is with the () around the form_name .. try it without () and it might work

Answer (score 1):

when you perform an action on Form2 or use a reference to it, then Form2 will be loaded again

before you do an action, you can first check wether Form2 is loaded, and if it is not you might decide not to perform the action

have a look at the following test project which consists of 2 forms:

Form1 has 3 command buttons and the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Form2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Unload Form2
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
  DoForm2
End Sub

Private Sub DoForm2()
  Dim frm As Form
  Dim blnLoaded As Boolean
  'check if Form2 is loaded
  blnLoaded = False
  For Each frm In Forms
    If frm.Name = "Form2" Then
      blnLoaded = True
    End If
  Next frm
  'perform action if Form2 is loaded
  If blnLoaded Then
    Form2.Caption = CStr(Now)
    'Print Form2.Name
  End If
End Sub
```

Form2 has no controls and the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
  MsgBox "Form2 loaded"
End Sub
```

Whenever Form2 is loaded a messagebox will show up.

To test do the following:

- Click Command1 : Form2 will load
- Click Command3 : The actual time will show in the titlebar of Form2
- Click Command2 : Form2 will unload
- Click Command3 : Nothing will happen and Form2 won't be loaded

Then remove the lines "*If blnLoaded Then*" and the corresponding "*End If*" and perform the same tests ... you will now see that Form2 will load on the last step

Instead writing something on the titlebar of Form2 you can also do the same test by reading the name of Form2, by removing the line "*Form2.Caption = CStr(Now)*" and uncommenting the line "*Print Form2.Name*" .. this will give the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try the following test project which consists of 2 forms:

Form1 has 2 command buttons on it and the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Form2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Form2.Hide
End Sub
```

Form2 is just the to be shown and hidden, it contains nothing

When you click on Command1 it will show Form2, when you click on Command2 it will hide Form2

You can also use the following code for Command2

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
  Unload Form2
End Sub
```

Both examples work for me. If your Form2 still remains then there is probably something referencing it or loading/showing it after you tried to close it

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I believe Form2 have some values & references.

Comment: Can we try with killing the form as we knew the form name? If so could you suggest some code?

Comment: You can unload it using the name, or you can loop through all forms and check for the .name property and unload the form which has the right name ... have a look at my other answer for some code which loops through all forms

Comment: After finding the exact form as per your code, Both unload(form_name) and unload form_name is not working. Any other way of unloading/killing the form?

Comment: what exactly does happen? can you put a msgbox in the form_load event to see if it is loaded anew? or place some break points on your code so you can see which routines are called when

Comment: Code contains a lot of loops & references. Im looking for statement which can close a individual form abruptly.

Comment: comment out those loops and references to find out where the problem originates ... in the end you might end up with everything commented out, but finally your form can be unloaded, then uncomment paret by part and see when it starts to go wrong

Comment: I've tried. The actual form from which im trying to close another form gets re-opened freshly internally. Still im able to call the other form methods but i dont suceed in form close.